# Help with solving a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help with the following differential equation:
$$\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt}+y(t)=x(t+1),\text{   } t>0$$
with $y(0)=0$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is x dependent on t ?

Comment: yes, x is dependent on t.

Comment: $x(t+1)=X(t)$ and solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt}+y(t)\right)e^t=\frac d{dt}(y(t)e^t)=x(t+1)e^t$$ and after integration,

$$y(t)=e^{-t}\int_0^t x(\color{green}t+1)e^{\color{green}t}\,d\color{green}t.$$

You can also write

$$y(t)=e^{-t-1}\int_1^{t+1} x(\color{green}t)e^{\color{green}t}\,d\color{green}t.$$

but this makes little difference.

Comment: Please don't use the same letter $t$ for the variable of integration and for the variable outside the integral.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: done ;-)

Comment: You didn't change it.

Comment: @RobertIsrael $t\ne\color{green}t$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying both sides by $e^t$ gives
$$ (e^ty(t))'=e^tx(t+1). $$
Integrating from 0 to $t$, you have
$$ e^ty(t)=\int_0^te^sx(s+1)ds $$
or
$$ y(t)=\int_0^te^{s-t}x(s+1)ds. $$